Can I trust ET Bell's commentary on the work of mathematicians?
I have had doubts about believing his writings since I found out that he exaggerated and fictionalized the lives of some mathematicians such as Galois and Cantor. So I'm curious about this. Did Bell accurately describe the achievements of mathematicians?

See Men of Mathematics: "It is not intended as a rigorous history, and includes many anecdotal accounts."

This does not mean that it is "wrong": for sure, it is not an history of mathematics, that cannot be reduced only to "big names".

In a word, no. Bell is consistent, if biographies he spices up to make up stories mathematical details he skips when they get in the way. Audin has an instructive chapter in her Remembering Sofya Kovalevskaya on Bell's treatment of achievements of women mathematicians, they are mostly omitted. What he did to specifics of Cole's factorization of 67-th Mersenne number (the same) is described in this answer. Bell's account of pre-17th century mathematics is best disregarded altogether.

You can trust his statements about mathematics. The biographical details are spiced by anecdotes.

Bell is famous for having been inspirational (see Freeman Dyson) but perhaps comparably famous for historical inaccuracy and including unfounded sometimes wrong descriptions. This has been known to contemporaries. See Broadbent's review of Men of Mathematics (1937).

@AlexandreEremenko, you cannot trust his statements on mathematics; see for example my answer.

E.T. Bell is wrong on many counts.  He is not considered as a serious historian by the professional historians, and for good reason: he is often inaccurate.  He improvised many "dramatisations" for better readership appeal, but this disqualified him as a historian.
One of my favorite examples is the following.  Bell waxed
poetic about infinitesimals having been
slain (p. 246),  scalped (p.~247), and disposed of (p. 290)
by the cleric of Cloyne.  Dismissing Bell's martial flourishes as merely verbal
excesses would be missing the point.  Bell has certainly been
criticized for other fictional excesses of his purportedly historical
writing (thus, Rothman writes: "[E. T.] Bell's account [of Galois's
life], by far the most famous, is also the most fictitious"
(p. 103); however, his confident choice of martial imagery
here cannot but reflect Bell's perception of a majority view among
professional mathematicians.  Bell is convinced that Berkeley refuted
infinitesimals only because triumvirate historians and mathematicians
told him so.
